# Working resident monitor source code from the sixties

Tags: open-source, emulator, operating-system

I teach operating systems and I talked about [resident monitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_monitor) in the sixties, but it would be nice to move from theory to peeking into a factual source code that even runs on an emulator.

As I understand,

http://simh.trailing-edge.com/

and the software directory at

http://simh.trailing-edge.com/software.html

contains binaries only.

Do you know some open source operating system monitors from the sixties, that work on an emulator?